# ASP.NET Button click redirect to new page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a Button programmatically.
I now want to redirect to a new aspx page on the click of this Button, such that we will enter into one of the methods of the new page (like page_load(), etc.)

Is this possible?

Eg:

```
Button oButton = new Button;
oButton.Text = "NextPage";
// Redirect to "Redirect.aspx" on click
```

But I am not able to find an entry point in Redirect.aspx where I can do some changes to the UI components once we get redirected to "Redirect.aspx"

Regards,

Parag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use query string parameters and depending on the value of param call the appropriate method in `Page_Load` of `Redirect.aspx`
e.g.

```
Redirect.aspx?val=1
```

in Redirect.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(...){
string var = Request.QueryString["val"];
if(var == "1")
some_method();
else
some_other_method();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to handle **Click** event of oButton.

```
Button oButton = new Button();
 oButton.Text = "NextPage";
 oButton.Click += (sa, ea) =>
     {
         Response.Redirect("Redirect.aspx");
   };
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the `PostBackUrl` property of the `Button` - this will post to the page specified, and if you need to access items from the previous page you can use the `PreviousPage` property:

```
Button oButton = new Button;
oButton.Text = "NextPage";
oButton.PostBackUrl = "Redirect.aspx";
```

Then in you wanted to get the value from, say, a `TextBox` on the previous page with an id of `txtMyInput`, you could do this (very simple example to give you an idea):

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   string myInputText = ((TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("txtMyInput")).Text;

   // Do something with/based on the value.

}
```

Just another example of how to accomplish what I think you're asking.

See [Button.PostBackUrl Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl.aspx) for more info.