# Redirecting to new page ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am having trouble trying to redirect to a new page after the button has been clicked. But this button also saves my datatable into an excel file. I want it to be able to save and redirect at the same time.

this is the code in the .CS file for the button

```
 protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       this.SaveExcel();
       Response.Redirect("Default.aspx", true);
    }
```

Also in the .aspx page i have this

```
<asp:Button ID="SaveButton" runat="server" Text="Save" 
    onclick="SaveButton_Click" Enabled="False" onclientclick="needToConfirm=false"/>
```

as you can see i have a onlclientclick function which is needed.

I have tried using javascript and also the Server.Transfer metothds. Has anyone got an idea how to do this?

Comment: check dis once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102647/asp-net-button-click-redirect-to-new-page

Comment: So what is the problem? Does your event handler get hit at all?

Comment: Problem is when i hit the Save button it saves but it will not redirect to the page

Comment: You say you have a javascript functiion, but `onclientclick="needToConfirm=false"`doesn't make sense... It is assignment to a variable, not a function call... Shouldn't it be `onclientclick="needToConfirm(false)"` or `onclientclick="needToConfirm() == false"`

Comment: Have you put a break point on `Response.Redirect("Default.aspx", true);`, debugged and seen that the line actually gets hit?

Comment: That JavaScript function is something completely different. I use that to display a pop up window displaying a message

Comment: And no the line doesnt get hit at all

Comment: If the line Response.Redirect(...) doesn't get hit in the debugger, *but* the Excel file gets saved, then the error has something to do with the SaveExcel(...) function. Maybe that function (or some nested code) makes a call to Response.End(), Response.Close(), Server.Transfer() etc which would stop execution of the page?  Please post the code for that function as well.

Answer (score 3):

Your `OnClientClick` should be in the following format.

```
OnClientClick="needToConfirm(); return false"
```

If this doesn't work there is an error in your JavaScript which is causing your c# code not to fire.

Comment: Thanks, But i found another way round this issue :)